# How can we access htmlhelper inside our custom helper?

Tags: cakephp

accessing model in helper is correct or wrong? in cakephp application.

How can we access htmlhelper inside our custom helper?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[Link to manual.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/102/Including-other-Helpers).

```
class LinkHelper extends AppHelper {
  var $helpers = array('Html');

  function makeEdit($title, $url) {
    $link = $this->Html->link($title, $url, array('class' => 'edit'));
  }
}
```

You can use any Model/Controller/Helper/etc anywhere, but **really shouldn't**. [Another manual link.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/531/Importing-Controllers-Models-Components-Behaviors-)